# White ceramic- irrespective of lighting

Tags: materials

In blender, we can get a green reflective color irrespective of the lighting:

[image: first]
or a yellow ceramic :
[image]
But I've been thinking of a way to get white ceramic like [these cups](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/e5/6c/2c/e56c2c13e77d244fc2879d77d781c9a4.jpg), irrespective of the lighting. We could fake through the use of HDR lighting or using the compositor, to seperately render out the cups and use a background. But, what would be a way to do so irrespective of the lighting.So, that we could take the same cup(or objects), to a bunch of different scenes and not get bugged with making adjustments. In a single scene, too much of lighting would occlude out the details. So, I'm really confused how to get this results.
All I get is a dull gray :
[image]
Please note that **the main point of it is to be irrespective of lighting.**

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want light effects without light? Your material is gray because massive amount of scene is gray, probably as we can't see whole node setup. And if I'm not getting it right and you want material which will behave in same manner in different environment you should check PBR materials.

Comment: Your examples are *respective* of lighting. When you change the light color it will effect the surface. Your question then doesn't make sense - can you clarify? Are you asking for a shadeless material or PBR material?

Comment: @LukeD and Jerryno, tell me if I were to bring a cup such as in the link provided in my question above, a white ceramic were to be put in a scene like above(the gray one), how would we render it? I mean, if we somehow do need a white cup in the same dull gray environment then how do we bring that up? I mean without compositing is it possible?, If we use emisson shader that would light the surrounding up and occulde it's own details, if only there were a way to possibly BOOST UP it's whiteness and unaffect the surroundings and maintain various other shaders(like diffuse, glossy, etc).

Comment: @Jerryno and LukeD, even if we were to put a fully white surrounding that would result in completely white surrounding. If possible, please try out (https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/e5/6c/2c/e56c2c13e77d244fc2879d77d781c9a4.jpg , ) to bring this image upon the same default gray plane, upon the same default background. With the same lighting. A real cup would be a bit dimmer but the originality of whiteness and glossy would still be there. Thanks for the pbr tip though, I am currently trying to find myself resources for it!!

Comment: @BumbleBee it's not how Cycles work. It's not how any ray-tracing renderer is working. To get reflections you need emission, lights, environment. I'm making answer for you with basic setup on how to get similar result with environment map but I will not get into PBR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Final]

### Environment texture:

First of all you'll need some *Environment Map*. I suggest to use HDRI imitating photo studio setup. You can find many of them, even for free.

[image: First]

After selecting one change *Strenght* accordingly to your needs. And you can see our environment.

[image: Second]

### Background:

To get gray background, or any other color create plane and extrude it with nice subtle curve.

[image: Third]

### Material:

I'm using simple *Diffuse/Glossy* mixed by *Fresnel* but you can go with any other setup. Remember that default color in Blender isn't pure white.

Blend file:

Here it's my blend file with HDRI map packed.

[image]

Comment: what if we need a white plane, it would be too reflective. Plus, if we wanted some square reflection on the surfaces of the meshes would we use emisson shaders? What would we do to avoid overlighting

Comment: what about the issue of multiple shadows with more than one mesh emitter? Do you have a way to not make them emit light that casts shadows?

Answer (score 1):

Making the material behave "irrespective of lighting" would make it look out of place in the scene so an alternative would be to make the object "whiter than white" - causing the material to amplify any incident light and making it appear more illuminated than it actually is. In this way you can adjust the amplification to make it appear white while leaving it within the scene.

This can be achieved by using an RGB node for the base colour and pass it through a MixRGB node set to Divide. With the divisor colour set to grey the colour passed to the Diffuse node will be greater than 1.0, amplifying the incident light (dividing by less than 1.0 increases the resultant colour).

[image: Diffuse amplify incident light]

You'd only need to adjust the divisor in each new scene to get the desired effect.

Comment: Wow this is a really good concept, by the way, How can I master stuffs with the math node.

Comment: Think of colours as separate red, green, blue channels - each with a value ranging from 0.0 (none) to 1.0 (100%). When you perform a mathematical operation using the MixRGB node you're effectively applying that operation on each channel separately. In the above case, the White on the input node is actually [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] ([R,G,B]) and the grey will be something like [0.25, 0.25, 0.25]. For each channel you have 1.0 / 0.25 = 4.0 (400%!). The Diffuse shader effectively does the same kind of thing and multiplies the incoming light by the colour so you get more light emitted than is coming in.

Comment: You can do something similar with the SeparateRGB node to separate out the colour into separate R, G, B channels - in which case you could use a Multiply Math node to get the same effect and then combine the channels back to a colour with the CombineRGB node. Doing it with a Divide MixRGB node is just a shortcut to get the same effect. The best way of getting a feel for it is to play around with each of the operations and inputs.